# How to draw a bar plot which shows average daily values for each month grouped by year?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart

I implemented the following code : `df.groupby(['month','year'], as_index=False).agg({"value": "mean"})`
I now have the dataframe with columns month, year and value where in the value is the average of each month of that year.
How do i make a bar plot showing year on x axis with each month's average vs values on the y axis?

Comment: Do you have a desired output image?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you can fin de guidelines for presenting a minimal, reproducible example